# Weird behaviour on subsetting a data.frame, when using a leveled variable

Tags: r

I just found a quite weird behaviour when subsetting a data.frame with a condition.
The problem is, when I use a leveled variable to subset, the subset gets filtered for all levels.

Here is an example where the error does not occur:

```
data <- data.frame(names = c("Bob", "Alice", "Joe"), ages = c(18, 20, 43), sizes = c(180, 160, 176), group = c("0021", "9430", "0021"))

for(i in 1:length(data$names)){
  print(paste("Name: ", data$names[i], sep=""))

  # print out all group members
  print("Group Members:")
  group = subset.data.frame(data, data$group == data$group[i])
  for(j in 1:length(group$names)){
    print(paste("Name: ", group$names[j], sep=""))
  }
  print("---------------------------------")
}
```

Now I am saving the `data$group[i]` into a variable and the data.frame does not get filtered at all:

```
data <- data.frame(names = c("Bob", "Alice", "Joe"), ages = c(18, 20, 43), sizes = c(180, 160, 176), group = c("0021", "9430", "0021"))

for(i in 1:length(data$names)){
  print(paste("Name: ", data$names[i], sep=""))
  group <- data$group[i]

  # print out all group members
  print("Group Members:")
  group = subset.data.frame(data, data$group == group)
  for(j in 1:length(group$names)){
    print(paste("Name: ", group$names[j], sep=""))
  }
  print("---------------------------------")
}
```

Can someone please explain to me, why this unexpected behaviour occurs? I do expect to get a String from the `data$group[i]` expression but get a leveled something.

Comment: The problem is your (wrong) use of `subset`. You should carefully study `help("subset")` including the examples and then stop using it. Use `data[data$group == group,]` instead. That does the scoping you expect.

Comment: @Roland thank you for the answer. I figured out, that `as.character(data$group)[i]` does convert the factor "value" to a string. But thanks for the hint, I am going to find out.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `factor` class. This is an issue with `subset`'s non-standard evaluation and the scoping following from it. `subset` takes `group` from `data` and not from the enclosing environment. You also should not use `$` within `subset`.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong as such in your code. `subset` has scoping issues when you have variable name same as your column name. If you change your `group` variable to any other name it would work fine.

```
for(i in 1:length(data$names)){
  print(paste("Name: ", data$names[i], sep=""))
  temp <- data$group[i] #Change here

  # print out all group members
  print("Group Members:")
  group = subset(data, group == temp)
  for(j in 1:length(group$names)){
     print(paste("Name: ", group$names[j], sep=""))
  }
  print("---------------------------------")
}
```

and that is the same reason why you should read [Why is `[` better than `subset`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/why-is-better-than-subset)

Comment: It should be `subset(data, group == temp)` if you insist on using `subset`.